# knitr: knitting chunks with parsing errors

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible to knit chunks with parsing errors?

I want to produce a document explaining some different types of errors one can find while coding in R, but it seems that I can't knit a chunk with parsing error, even with `error = TRUE`.

For example, this chunk works fine and it shows the error messages:

````
```{r sum character, error = TRUE}
"1" + "2"
```
````

However, this chunk doesn't:

````
```{r missing parenthesis, error = TRUE}
f <- function(x){
  z <- sum(x
  #
  y <- x + 1
  return(x + y + z)
}
```
````

It gives the error: `Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src)`.

The idea here would be to show all error messages in the chunk "missing parenthesis", is this possible?

Comment: That is not supported in the evaluate package (on which knitr depends), and you may file a feature request to https://github.com/hadley/evaluate so I can think about it when I have got time. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Yihui I filed the feature request!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [has become possible](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/commit/cc0c5847a9990ae91467a24a671c8688bc5b84ec) since the **evaluate** package >= v0.8.4 (which is expected to be v0.9 on CRAN in the future). For now, you can install **evaluate** [from Github](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate).