# Chunk with eval=FALSE still evaluates on R Sweave

Tags: r, knitr, tex, sweave, chunks

I'm working on some education manuals in spanish for a course, so I'm making a Sweave document with some chunks and I'm trying to make an example of an error message. But first I need to show the souce of that error, so I'm using this code, since I don't want the code evaluating I'm using eval=FALSE:

```
<<eval=FALSE, error=TRUE,tidy=FALSE>>=
c(1,2 3)
#falta una coma
@
```

But the code is still evaluating and it's not letting me print the document, giving me this error message

> (chunk 306) 5305:7: unexpected numeric constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is being parsed, not evaluated.   If you have current versions of the `knitr` and `evaluate`, this should result in a warning in the `knitr` log, it won't stop the run.  I'm using `knitr` 1.16 and `evaluate` 0.10.1 and things are fine.  See [knitr: knitting chunks with parsing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842682/knitr-knitting-chunks-with-parsing-errors) for a bit more on this.

(BTW, I think you're using `knitr`, not `Sweave`.  They're different.  `Sweave` can't handle this.  If you really are using `Sweave`, switch to `knitr`.  The switch is not hard, and brings a lot of benefits.)

Comment: I updated my `evaluate` and `knitr` versions but I'm still having the error. I guess I'm using `Sweave` and that's the reason. Any documentation to help me change from `Sweave` to `knitr`? Thank you.